# Yii: Error when trying to use a 'uniqe' rule with a condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii1.x

I'm dealing with an Yii 1.1x website.

I have a model which have a title and a category id.

I'm trying to prevent from the user the possibility to enter the same title in the exact same category. (the same title in a different category is ok).

I tried using the following rule but I get an error when testing it (by entering a duplicate title in the same category)

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('str_title, id_category', 'required'),
        array('str_title', 'unique', 'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'`id_category`=:idcategory',
            'params'=>array(
                ':idcategory'=>$this->id_category
            )
        )),

    );
}
```

As mentioned, when I try to enter a duplicate title within the same category I get this error message:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT 1 FROM `posts` `t` WHERE (`id_category`=:idcategory) AND (`t`.`str_title`=:ycp0) LIMIT 1
```

Anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: Try changing the condition to this `':idcategory'=>$this->id_category`

Comment: sorry. that was a typo in my question. not in my code. still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use attributes values in `rules()` method, since it is called before attributes are set:

1. Call `rules()` to get validators config.
2. Set attributes.
3. Run validation.

You should use existing extension ([example](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/unique-attributes-validator)) for validation of composite keys or write own validator for this (it is not that hard, usually inline validator takes like 5-10 lines of code).